# Using the next() method on an array

Tags: java, arrays

Is there a way to make a for loop that stalls and will only print the next element when next is called?  It seems everything else runs smoothly, at this points I'm typing because it won't let me post my question unless I explain more. I feel my problem is quite direct though.

Comment: Arrays don't have next() methods, and neither do `for` loops. What are you talking about?

Comment: ahh my teacher is being so confusing about his expectations for our assignments, he create requiresments by providing the code we have to make work in the main. one of them was Fibonacci fib = new Fibonacci(); 
System.out.println(fib.next()); // prints 1

Comment: i think he wants us to write our own next code that overrides the one in java, but i don't know what would go in it, hence my question at the top of the code

Comment: What do you mean by "_when next is called_"?  Who will call _next_, when will they call it, and what will they expect to happen when they do? None of these things are obvious.

Comment: at the moment i call fib.next() in the main. i imagine i have to make an overriding next() method in my Fibonacci class, ever time you call next() the next fibonacci number is printed.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want a [generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).  Failing that, one could conjure up something with `static` values and current state...

Comment: Sounds like he wants you build your own linked list (of sorts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a next() method, you can create one inside your Fibonacci.
Create a global variable

```
int index = 0;
```

then your next() will look as follows

```
public int next(){
  return fib[index++];
}
```

Then you can use next() function to print next element.

Comment: You need `return fib[++index];`

Comment: Whenever you call next() if will print the next available element in array, for the first time it will be 0th element. 
++index will skip the 0th element

Answer (score 0):

I think you're after something like a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

> [`BlockQueue#take`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29)
>
> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary
>   until an element becomes available.

Answer (score 0):

My final code for next looks like this:

```
 public int next()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i< howMany; i++)
        { 
        if ( fib[i] == currentNum)
        index = i+1;
        }
        return fib[index++];
    }
```

That way if the nth number is asked first, next can be used as well to print each next element from that position in the array.
Thank you!

Comment: There are so many magic variables that I can't be sure that this works just from a high-level glance...It also doesn't convey to us how you *generate* the array either.

Comment: I'd be almost better to create your [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html)